# snprintf of unsigned long appending a comma

Tags: c++, c, printf

I try to convert a `unsigned long` into a character string, appending a comma at the end of the it. When compiling and running the test code you can find below, I get the following output:

```
"1234," "1234"
"1234"
```

The test code is:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

int main () {

    unsigned long c = 1234;
    char ch[50];
    char ch1[50];

    sprintf(ch, "%lu,", c);
    std::cout << "\"" << ch << "\"" << " \"" << c << "\"" << std::endl;

    snprintf(ch1, 5, "%s", ch); 
    std::cout << "\"" << ch1 << "\"" << std::endl;

    return 1;
}
```

As far as I understand, `ch` should be of length 5, 4 digits plus 1 for the comma.

Do I miss an extra plus one for the termination character?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size that is passed to `snprintf` includes the terminating null character. Although it is not printed, it still takes space in the buffer.

You should pass `strlen(ch) + 1` instead. Or even better, just `sizeof(ch1)` will suffice since you want to accommodate the entire result before filling the buffer.

Also make sure that the destination buffer is always of a sufficient size, equal to or greater than the size you pass to `snprintf`. In your particular case it can hardly happen, but in general you should keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes (including the trailing null byte  ('\0')) to str.

So yes, you should have a length of 6 to get the comma as well.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ way:

```
#include <string>

unsigned long int c = 1234;

std::string s = "\"" + std::to_string(c) + ",\"";
std::string t = '"' +  std::to_string(c) + ',' + '"'; // alternative
```

Comment: compiling I get: `error: ‘to_string’ is not a member of ‘std’`

Comment: @ezdazuzena: This requires a modern compiler (with C++11 support). In GCC, say `-std=c++0x`; MSVC10 supports this as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tagged another answer as correct, since the question was with respect to snprintf. Any, thanks for you lesson!

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote, you miss an extra space for the termination character.

> The functions snprintf() and vsnprintf() write at most size bytes
>   (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str.

Answer (score 0):

As several people has pointed out, you need to include enough space for the null terminator.

It's always worth checking the result returned from snprintf is what you think it should be, as well.

Lastly, I'd recommend using snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), etc, etc)

Your less likely to get embarrassing results if the 2nd parameter happens to be larger than the actual space you've got available.