# Why snprintf changes output string?

Tags: c, gcc, printf

I try to convert some numbers to string using snprintf. The name1 should have the same digits after comma as name2.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define length 50

  int main()
  {
  char name1 [length]; 
  char name2 [length];
  double step= 0.00001;
  unsigned long long int iterMax  =100000000000; 
  int k;

  for (k = 0; k <= 20; k++)  
    { printf("numbers :  k = %2d ; k*step = %f ;", k, k*step); 
      snprintf(name1,length+1,"%f", iterMax+k*step); /* */
      snprintf(name2,length+1, " %f", k*step); /*  */
      printf("strings : k*step =  %s ; iterMax+k*step = %s \n",name2, name1);  
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Compile it with :

```
 gcc t.c  -Wall
```

Output is :

```
./a.out 
numbers :  k =  0 ; k*step = 0.000000 ;strings : k*step =   0.000000 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000000 
numbers :  k =  1 ; k*step = 0.000010 ;strings : k*step =   0.000010 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000015 
numbers :  k =  2 ; k*step = 0.000020 ;strings : k*step =   0.000020 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000015 
numbers :  k =  3 ; k*step = 0.000030 ;strings : k*step =   0.000030 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000031 
numbers :  k =  4 ; k*step = 0.000040 ;strings : k*step =   0.000040 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000046
```

The results are the same ( digits aftter comma ) when iterMax   is smaller , for example 100000000 :

```
numbers :  k =  0 ; k*step = 0.000000 ;strings : k*step =   0.000000 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000.000000 
numbers :  k =  1 ; k*step = 0.000010 ;strings : k*step =   0.000010 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000.000010 
numbers :  k =  2 ; k*step = 0.000020 ;strings : k*step =   0.000020 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000.000020 
numbers :  k =  3 ; k*step = 0.000030 ;strings : k*step =   0.000030 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000.000030 
numbers :  k =  4 ; k*step = 0.000040 ;strings : k*step =   0.000040 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000.000040
```

The ULLONG_MAX =  18446744073709551615  is greater then iterMax.

How can I resolve that ?

TIA

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: You're expecting very large floating point numbers to be very precise at the very-small-decimal end of things. That's just not how floating point works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765744/precision-in-c-floats, and many, many more questions about floating point precision.

Comment: You are using `snprintf` and explicitly asking it to overrun your buffer? *Why???*

Comment: If the first argument to `snprintf()` is `char buffer[SOMESIZE];`, the second argument should normally be `sizeof(buffer)`.  Specifying a larger value than the array size invites the sort of buffer overflow that `snprintf()` is intended to prevent — and does prevent when use correctly.

Comment: I have added +1 after : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126637/snprintf-of-unsigned-long-appending-a-comma

Comment: The advice in that answer "You should pass strlen(ch) + 1 instead." is not so good.  Follow the "Or even better, just sizeof(ch1)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a problem of `double` precision. There are plenty of other questions which explain more about IEEE-754 floating-point numbers, but I'll sum up the relevant points here:

1. `double` and family effectively store numbers in scientific notation with limited precision. This means the larger the number, the less accurate it'll be.
2. Most numbers use base 2. As such, the decimal `0.1` cannot be stored exactly (instead, it's something like `0.10000000149011612`)

As such, the number `100000000000.000010` is "large", so it becomes less accurate after the decimal place. In fact, once you get towards about `4503599627370496`, you can't even store all integers!

Comment: In ref to "They work in base 2, not base 10.":  `double` uses base `FLT_RADIX` which is _commonly_ `2`.  `IEEE-754` defines both base 2 and base 10 numbers.  The binary formats being far more common.

Comment: snprintf(name1,length+1,"%f", log10(iterMax)+k*step); works good. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Cast to a `long double` in order to get more precision:

```
snprintf(name1,length+1,"%Lf", (long double)iterMax+k*step);
```

Output:

```
numbers :  k =  0 ; k*step = 0.000000 ;strings : k*step =   0.000000 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000000 
numbers :  k =  1 ; k*step = 0.000010 ;strings : k*step =   0.000010 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000010 
numbers :  k =  2 ; k*step = 0.000020 ;strings : k*step =   0.000020 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000020 
numbers :  k =  3 ; k*step = 0.000030 ;strings : k*step =   0.000030 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000030 
numbers :  k =  4 ; k*step = 0.000040 ;strings : k*step =   0.000040 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000040 
numbers :  k =  5 ; k*step = 0.000050 ;strings : k*step =   0.000050 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000050 
numbers :  k =  6 ; k*step = 0.000060 ;strings : k*step =   0.000060 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000060 
numbers :  k =  7 ; k*step = 0.000070 ;strings : k*step =   0.000070 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000070 
numbers :  k =  8 ; k*step = 0.000080 ;strings : k*step =   0.000080 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000080 
numbers :  k =  9 ; k*step = 0.000090 ;strings : k*step =   0.000090 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000090 
numbers :  k = 10 ; k*step = 0.000100 ;strings : k*step =   0.000100 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000100 
numbers :  k = 11 ; k*step = 0.000110 ;strings : k*step =   0.000110 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000110 
numbers :  k = 12 ; k*step = 0.000120 ;strings : k*step =   0.000120 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000120 
numbers :  k = 13 ; k*step = 0.000130 ;strings : k*step =   0.000130 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000130 
numbers :  k = 14 ; k*step = 0.000140 ;strings : k*step =   0.000140 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000140 
numbers :  k = 15 ; k*step = 0.000150 ;strings : k*step =   0.000150 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000150 
numbers :  k = 16 ; k*step = 0.000160 ;strings : k*step =   0.000160 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000160 
numbers :  k = 17 ; k*step = 0.000170 ;strings : k*step =   0.000170 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000170 
numbers :  k = 18 ; k*step = 0.000180 ;strings : k*step =   0.000180 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000180 
numbers :  k = 19 ; k*step = 0.000190 ;strings : k*step =   0.000190 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000190 
numbers :  k = 20 ; k*step = 0.000200 ;strings : k*step =   0.000200 ; iterMax+k*step = 100000000000.000200
```

Comment: If the compiler doesn't support `%Lf`, it probably doesn't support `long double` either.

Comment: snprintf(name1,length+1,"%Lf", (long double) iterMax+k*step) works good for me .

Comment: Even if `long double` is supported, it _may_ not have more range/precision than `double`.  Likely OP does not have such a weak complier.

Comment: @Adam Using `length+1` may cause trouble.  See Jonathan Leffler comment.  Better to use `snprintf(name1, sizeof name1, ...`

Answer (score 0):

When printing more than `DBL_DIG` significant decimal digits, the effects of a `double` finite format may appear.

Example:

```
#include <float.h>

printf("%d\n", DBL_DIG);
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DIG - 1, 100000000000.0 + 0.00001);
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DIG - 1 + 10, 100000000000.0 + 0.00001);

15
1.00000000000000e+11
1.000000000000000152587891e+11
```

`1.00000000000000e+11` has 15 significant decimal digits. (14 to the right of '.')

---

Regardless of the base (2, 10, 16, etc.) used for a `double`, only so many decimal digits 
are "round-trip"-able.

Example: (Assuming DBL_DIG is 10, the *minimum* specified by C)

```
double x;
scanf("%lf", &x);
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DIG - 1, x);
printf("%.*e\n", DBL_DIG - 1 + 5, x);
```

Should the user entered "12345678901234567890", the output would be "1.234567890e19" and "1.234567890?????e19", the "?????" not begin specified by C.